# "Switched off at the main" phrase meaning

Tags: phrases, literature

I've encountered the following phrase in a Jeeves and Wooster book, *[The code of the Woosters](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Code_of_the_Woosters/VsPgDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22He%20had%20been%20beaming%20like%20a%20searchlight%22&pg=PT66&printsec=frontcover)*:

> He had been beaming like a searchlight until I mentioned this aspect
> of the matter, and the radiance suddenly disappeared as if it had been
> switched off **at the main.**

I'm trying to guess the meaning of the phrase "at the main" here and I suppose that it metaphorically refers to switching the searchlight off by pressing the main power button or something like this. Am I right?

Comment: "Jeeves" is the name of the butler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *main* refers to the *main* pipe or conduit that carries some service into a building. (A slightly different term *mains electricity* refers to the electricity that enters your house, through the *mains*, which are the *main breakers*.)

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=main

The idea is that is when you close that conduit or shut down that breaker then all power, all fluid, all whatever, goes out of the building -- it is quick, obvious, and complete.

The simile (not a metaphor) is that the experience shut off all light from his face as if it had been shut off at the main.

Comment: In Britain, where the author is from, we may have, entering a building, a **gas main**, a **water main**, and some **electricity mains**. The first two are a single pipe each, the last comes via a number of wires, either two or three.

Answer (score 3):

"The main" or "the mains" refers to the electrical supply to a house or building. So you have the meaning right.

Here's a dictionary definition:
[American Heritage Dictionary "main"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Main)

> 2. The principal pipe or conduit in a system for conveying water, gas, oil, or other utility